# Xcode 6.0.1 - iOS Simulator Black Screen

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode6

I've seen lots of questions about this - however none of them are solving my issue.

The Setup is as follows

```
OSX Mavericks 10.9.5
Xcode 6.0.1
iOS Simulator 8.0 (550.1)
```

I've tried now with 5 different Xcode projects, that are working with another machine with identical setups, except this one isn't working.

Every time I launch the simulator, whether or not it's with an App running, or standalone I get the same.

When I run from Xcode I get this message ->

```
An error was encountered while running (Domain = com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError, Code = 146)
```

The things I've tried are:

- Reset all Content and Settings (when I click and confirm this - nothing happens at all)
- Removed all devices from the simulators, and re-created them
- Made sure everything is up to date
- Cleaned all projects, SEVERAL times
- Restarted machine inbetween doing everything under the sun
- Deleted Derived Data

This has been happening for 3 days now.

Suggestions please!

Comment: upvoted just because I feel your pain!

Comment: Delete also Derived Data? Someone else said he have to delete then re-add pods related to project.

Comment: I have as it happens :( I've updated the question to match! thanks for reminding me

Comment: I am feeling that same pain now. I can't stop cursing at Apple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This probably isn't the "official" answer, but my solution to solve this was literally bin xcode, empty trash, then reinstall from the App store.

Answer (score 2):

[This post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1053853#1053853) on the Apple Developer Forums has a bunch of highly relevant information. It doesn't appear to directly address your issue, but try this:

1. Turn up debug logging for the Simulator:

```
defaults write com.apple.iphonesimulator DebugLogging -bool YES
defaults write com.apple.CoreSimulator DebugLogging -bool YES
```

2. Quit and relaunch the iOS Simulator.
3. Check `~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/*.log` for more information.